# how to change the array format to the object format?

Tags: javascript

How to use javascript to change the array to the object format? Thanks!

```
[ "16-282", "16-311", "16-320", "17-275", "17-276" ]
```

object format：

```
[{
    id: 16,
    Options: [282, 311, 320],
  },
  {
     id: 17,
     Options: [275, 276],
  }]
```

My Code:

```
test() {
  var option = ["16-282", "16-311", "16-320", "17-275", "17-276"];


  var finalResult = option.map((item, index) => ({id: item, Options: item,  }));
  console.log(finalResult);
},
```

Comment: Can you please share your attempt? This problem is very straight forward. I accept it may not be as simple for you are few of us. And this is why your attempt is necessary. It tells us what level you are and based on that, we can draft our answer

Comment: @Rajesh Very diplomatic way to put it! :)

Comment: @charlietfl I thought my initial comment was a bit rude. Hence dialed down the tone. But in a way I meant every word. I remember my initial days and these comments can have some impact on individual's mind. Hence I prefer explaining small details as caveat

Comment: @shuk what you want is a "groupBy" operation using the id as keys in an object. Example using reduce() and a Map https://jsfiddle.net/0fjbh3d4/

Comment: @shuk I've linked an alternative commented solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/rdjzwy7q/ (The solution suggested above is better though)

Comment: @charlietfl @ Edrich 
This problem has bothered me for a long time，it is now fixed. Thank you so much for helping out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a "groupBy" operation using the id as object keys and a new object as values

Solution using Array#reduce() and  a Map

```js
var option = ["16-282", "16-311", "16-320", "17-275", "17-276"];

const group = option.reduce((m, c) => {
  const [id, val] = c.split('-');
  const obj = m.get(id) || { id, options: [] };
  obj.options.push(val);
  return m.set(id, obj)
}, new Map)

console.log([...group.values()])
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%!important;
  top: 0
}
```

Comment: [Opinionated]: I prefer using objects instead of `.map` if my keys are strings. If i have complex structure as key, then `Map` makes more sense to me over creating hash and using object.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with your code:

```
var finalResult = option.map((item, index) => ({id: item, Options: item,  }));
```

Here you are using `.map`. It will return an array of `n` length with parsed output.

---

Based on your output, you need to group the values based on part that is before `-`. This can be done in many ways, but I'll use `for` as its easy to understand:

**Idea:**

- Create an object to hold groups. Object and not array as Objects are key-value pair structure. So your groupId would be key and value will be the value to store.
- Now loop over the `option` array.

  - For every iteration, split `item` using hyphen(`-`). First part is your key and second is your value.
  - Check if this key exists in `group`. If yes, push current value to the `Options` array.
  - If it does not exists, initialize it with default structure:
    `{ id: groupKey, Options: [ groupValue ] }`

**Sample:**

```js
var option = ["16-282", "16-311", "16-320", "17-275", "17-276"];

var groups = {};

for (var i = 0; i< option.length; i++) {
  var parts = option[i].split('-');
  var groupKey = parts[0];
  var groupValue = parts[1];
  
  // Check if the groupKey exists in group
  if (groups[ groupKey ] !== undefined) {
    groups[ groupKey ].Options.push(groupValue)
  } else {
    groups[ groupKey ] = { id: groupKey, Options: [ groupValue ] }
  }
}

console.log(groups)
```

---

Now that you have groups, you just need to loop over this object and make an array.

An accumulation of above grouping idea and creating array is as follows:

```js
var option = ["16-282", "16-311", "16-320", "17-275", "17-276"];

const groups = option.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const [ id, value ] = item.split('-');
  acc[ id ] = acc[ id ] || { id, Options: [ ]};
  acc[ id ].Options.push(value);
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.values(groups);
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100vh!important;
}
```